# Donating/Gifting money to an individual in India

Tags: india, gift-tax, gifts, donation, gift-certificate

An NRI (A) decides to donate/gift some money to an Indian citizen (B) residing in India. Currently the money is in an NRO account (of A) in India and A would transfer the money to a savings account of B. Depending on the amount of money, do A and/or B need to submit any paperwork to the Income Tax department of India?

Comment: By donation do you mean gift?

Comment: Yes, you can consider it a gift.